# Help with notes of chromatic harmonica!! I have only 3 days to practise!

Tags: harmonica

I have to play the game of thrones main tune . I have a chromatic Harmonica 24 hole in total.
I researched and got this tutorial from the web . But I don't understand where are the c d e f g a b c notes located . I humbly request if anyone can give what hole numbers are c d e f g a b c etc notes are located . Please I have to play in 10 days[image]
This is the tutorial.

This is my tower 24 hole Harmonica

[image]

Comment: The first line of the chart appears to contain the answer already. VTC as unclear.

Answer (score 4):

It's going to depend a lot on what key you play the piece in. It's Cm in the original, which will not be too bad for you, as it modulates to C maj. When you blow 4 or 5 notes simultaneously, button out, you're playing C, E and G. Don't bother counting holes, just listen to the notes, and get them down to only 3 playing. These need to sound like the 1st 3 notes of the chorus of 'Obladi oblada' and Stevie Wonder's 'Sir Duke' intro., when played low to high. The lowest note of the 3 will be C, a very good place to start. Keep that sound in mind, go up 2 other blow notes, and the next after those is another C Use the chart of C in your question and you'll soon work out the other notes in between. There's going to be an Eb near the start: that's suck, button in, on the hole to the right of the C

Answer (score 0):

Your picture shows 12 pairs of holes.  `1` refers to the lowest pair, probably at the end away from the slide button.  I think it is upside down in the picture.  Often numbers are stamped on the top of the case.  This may be unusual. In any case, count pairs of holes starting with the low notes.  4 pairs makeup an octave.

```
1 2 3 4 5 ....
C E G C C E G C C E G C
 D F A B D F A B D F A B
```

The hardest 1st step is learning to blow or draw on just one pair of holes at a time.  There are instructions on how shape your lips and use your tongue.  I doubt if you will learn this in just a few days.

Comment: Pictures of guitar chord windows? Help!

Comment: My tongue hurts just looking at this! Seriously though, looks like a glitch with the jTab plugin. If you try to edit this answer you can see that the guitar tab is unintentional.

Comment: Guitar chords??

Comment: @hpaulj Your diagram of the holes was being misinterpreted as jTab code, and was rendering as guitar tabs for cords C E G C etc. I've fixed it using the pre tag which renders text "preformatted" in fixed width.

Comment: I wrote it, and viewed it, on a tablet, with the app, so didn't see any special formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I have a tower chromatic harmonica and this is the key chart I follow:

[image: key chart 1]
[image: key chart 2]